# Do ASP.NET MVC helper methods like Html.DropDownList() encode the output HTML?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am just wondering if I have to worry about encoding the values that get output when I use HTML helpers like `Html.DropDownList()`.

If so, how do I encode them? It's easy to do if I were building the drop down manually -- just wrap each value with "`Html.Encode()`". However, I don't know how to do this when using HTML helpers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the values are encoded automatically, so there's no reason to do it yourself.  Here's a snippet from the actual ASP.NET MVC 1.0 source code that you can download from codeplex (in SelectExtensions.cs):

```
    private static string ListItemToOption(SelectListItem item) {
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("option") {
            InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text)
        };
        if (item.Value != null) {
            builder.Attributes["value"] = item.Value;
        }
        if (item.Selected) {
            builder.Attributes["selected"] = "selected";
        }
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
```

Comment: When using most helpers in ASP.NET MVC it's critical that you do *not* encode text yourself. If you do then you end up with double-encoded text, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

They do.

If you want to do it yourself it's `Html.Encode()` and `Html.AttributeEncode()` depending on where in the HTML you're encoding.

Comment: Deleted my answer.  Are you sure they always encode text before rendering html?  I'm pretty sure they weren't in the beta...

Comment: Answering my own question--yes, they do encode all output in the beta.